# Inflector.NET not correctly attributed to Andrew Peters in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, open-source, attribution

Inflector is not correctly attributed in [Stack Exchange Data Explorer code base](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/Inflector.cs). The source inaccurately lists Subsonic as the source and include the BSD license. This license may or may not be compatible with Andrew Peter's license terms of Inflector. The original URL for Inflector.NET was http://andrewpeters.net/inflectornet/ however it is no longer currently accessible so I am not sure what license should be included with Inflector however it should correctly be attributed to him.

Comment: You are referencing a link that is unavailable?  That probably won't work very well.  Do you have any other links to show what you mean?

Comment: @jjnguy - see http://web.archive.org/web/20080514125039/http://andrewpeters.net/ for the evidence at least, a few more details in my separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The respective code has been [integrated into Castle.ActiveRecord](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs) under the **Apache 2.0 License** by Andrew Peters himself and could likely be [used as is from there](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs) accordingly, see the first comments from the [Inflector.NET page as of 20080514](http://web.archive.org/web/20080514125039/http://andrewpeters.net/) via [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://andrewpeters.net/) (unfortunately the original source archive itself is not available there as usual):

Alex Henderson asks:

> **Alex Henderson Thu, 05 Jul 2007 04:25:56 CDT**
>
> Out of curiosity, does Inflector.Net
>   offer any advantages over the Castle
>   Project’s Inflector in ActiveRecord
>   http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/ActiveRecord/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs
>   it’s seem very similar, and I wonder
>   if perhaps there’s an opportunity to
>   merge the two at some point?

And Andrew Peters answers:

> **Andrew Thu, 05 Jul 2007 04:57:47 CDT**
>
> Hi Alex,
>
> They are one in the same. After I did
>   the original port I also wrote the
>   pluralization patch for ActiveRecord.
>   :-) I’ll keep it available here in
>   case anyone wants it on it’s own.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/master/SubSonic.Core/Extensions/Inflector.cs

Anyway SEDE is using this only in one place to pluralize "view", appending "s" will do for now.

http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=f66ccaa8468f05376cff6028fc71e4f831be0028

Comment: Apparently Andrew Peters has integrated his code into Castle.ActiveRecord under the Apache 2.0 License himself, see http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs and [my separate answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61380/inflector-net-not-correctly-attributed-to-andrew-peters-in-stack-exchange-data-ex/61405#61405) for details.

Comment: meh ... we are using this in one spot, it really does not matter

Comment: I'm rather shocked to see a developer of stackoverflow say that correctly attributing code source doesn't matter

Comment: @dotnetchris ... you are totally out of context here. "It does not matter, I can not be bothered finding out who owns this code, so I ripped it out"